# Is pumpkin soup still good to drink cold?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

What are the benefits of Pumpkin Soup hot vs cold?

Is it still worth drinking cold?

Is it better than other potions still?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **Pumpkin Soup** heals 8 hearts when hot, and 4 when cold.

The **Heart Potion** that you can buy from the Bazaar's Potion Shop (for 20 Rupees) restores eight hearts when you drink it. You can also upgrade this potion - **Heart Potion+** heals all of your hearts, and **Heart Potion++** is essentially two helpings of **Heart Potion+** (so it can heal all of your hearts twice).

The Revitalizing Potion that you can buy from the Bazaar's Potion Shop (for 30 Rupees) restores four hearts to Link and completely repair his shields. Bertie can improve the potency of the potion: **Revitalizing Potion+** repairs Link's shield when it is damaged, and provides eight Heart Containers worth of healing; **Revitalizing Potion++** is essentially two helpings of **Revitalizing Potion+**.

So yes, it is still worth drinking cold, however, there are much better things you can fill your bottles with if you are willing to spend the money.

Comment: Good answer, I myself don't bother with potions, I just fill my bottles with fairies...

Comment: @JeffMercado Ok. is this stuff listed in the [faq] or just buried somewhere in [meta]?

Comment: @CyberSkull: Actually on a couple of my older Zelda posts such as [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/38382/6) and [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/38699/3).

Answer (score 2):

Hot soup restores 8 hearts, cold only restores 4. Whether this is better than other potions I can't say because I don't own the game.